# Convert 2 arrays into one 2 dimensional array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I developed code for get mysql table data.

```
$latvalue = Array();
    $logvalue = Array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstore, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $latvalue[] = $row['lat']; 
    $logvalue[] = $row['log']; 
}
```

So its like (45 ,56,34)
            (10 ,20,30) for example

I want to combine those 2 arrays into one 2 dimensional array.

Example

```
 $data = array
 (
   0 => array(45, 10),
  1 => array(56, 20),
  2 => array(34, 30),
  );
```

I can't figure out logic to do this. Please help.

Comment: If you do a `SELECT lat, long ...` then you just do:  `$data[] = $row;` in the loop.  Or just `while ($data[] = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstore, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code to do it:

```
$latlong = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstore, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $latlong[] = array($row['lat'], $row['log']);
}
```